# Clear logs for specific apps?

Tags: disk-space, logs, macos

I am running my boot drive off a SSD. I'm paying attention to try to keep it from filling up, and sorting folders by size, I notice the library/application support folder has logs generated by specific apps. For example, one program that creates an updated backup of my data drive shows a size of 4GB.

Is there any general rule for what can be deleted safely?

Edit - one that I just found, log.smbd.old is 8.9GB. It was created after a reboot, and there's a new log.smbd file which is small. Since I am running the OS on a smallish SSD, these files are troubling. Is there another way to keep the drive clean? e.g. a small app running in the background that will either quickly identify, or preferably, automatically remove these old log files? Note - I am running Snow Leo, 10.6.8 on a MacPro.

Comment: Which application is this?

Comment: I mean "specific apps" opposed to the system generated logs. When looking in the library folder, many apps generate logs.

Comment: Generally speaking logs can always be deleted.